# Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I add this line:

```
var card = bd.entradas_saidas
             .Where(e => e.cardID == es.cardID)
             .OrderBy(e => e.cardID)
             .Last();
```

I get this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

How can I resolve this?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddReport(entradas_saidas es)
{
    using (EMSistec bd = new EMSistec())
    {
        try
        {
            // ViewData["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            var card = bd.entradas_saidas
                         .Where(e => e.cardID == es.cardID)
                         .OrderBy(e => e.cardID).Last();
                   
            bd.entradas_saidas.Add(es);
            bd.SaveChanges();

            return Json(new { msg = "SUCCESS" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } 
        catch (Exception) 
        {
            return Json(new { msg = "ERROR" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging, this value always is null.

Comment: What is the error message on the exception?  Are there any inner exceptions?  Any other fields on the exception with additional data?  The *exception type alone* doesn't really tell us much.  You should be catching and examining the actual exception object.

Comment: @David When I run/debug the project with that line on code appears that message on the Output. Screenshot of Output: https://prnt.sc/wvlr-6CsIlJ9.
How Do I catch the actual exception object? Do you mean the variable "card"?.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/exception-handling

Answer (score 1):

That exception means that something in your query cannot be translated into SQL. Remember that EF tries to convert your Linq into SQL (or at least, any code up to an enumerator) and run it in the database engine.

If I remember correctly, `Last` isn't supported in SQL, which would explain the problem.

Try changing your query to the following and see if it works...

```cs
var card = bd.entradas_saidas
             .Where(e => e.cardID == es.cardID)
             .OrderByDescending(e => e.cardID)
             .First();
```

All I've done is reverse the order of the sort and taken the first item. `First` is definitely supported.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Avrohim Yisroel, that help, thanks. Can you add me on discord or something so I can ask another thing?

Comment: If you have another question, feel free to ask it here. That way other people can help as well